# как преобразовать изображение png в двоичный код 1,0 без PIL/numpy Python

Tags: python, micropython

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет.

конечная цель - проецировать изображение на монохромный/светодиодный экран
Имеем маленькое изображение, чернобелое, изначально в png формате. размеры в районе 100х100рх а то и меньше. (Пример в самом начале)

Имеем Paint.net который позволяет конвертировать в bmp, jpeg, tiff, tga и что-то там ещё, если нужно уточню.
Также имеем GIMP который превращает нам png в pbm.

Вопрос. как легко и быстро превратить изображение в (перфокарту) табличку из нулей и единичек.
Вроде как pbm уже состоит из нулей и единичек. Но у меня получилось прочитать его только как последовательность байтов.
И да, план в том, чтобы потом на микроконтроллере всё это запускать. Так что нужно всё сделать минимумом базового функционала

Answer (score 7):

Нужно уменьшить количество цветов до двух - тогда один пиксель займет один бит. Но ещё и картинка должна получится читаемая.

Берем Gimp и картинку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

яркость-контраст, кадрирование, масштабирование, обесцвечивание до чб и в конце **"изображение-режим-индексированное"** и получается такая картинка под однобитный жк-дисплей. (256*256 увеличенно)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не очень удобное изображение для 100*100, но ещё узнаваемо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажимаем экспортировать - и выбираем формат "заголовочный файл h"

```
/*  GIMP header image file format (INDEXED): /home/eri/Pictures/1567355672115958410.h  */

static unsigned int width = 256;
static unsigned int height = 256;



static unsigned char header_data_cmap[256][3] = {
    {  0,  0,  0},
    {255,255,255},
    {255,255,255},
    {255,255,255},
```

....

```
};
static unsigned char header_data[] = {
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,
    0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,
    0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,
    0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,
```

...

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
};
```

`header_data_cmap` можно удалить - это для цветных изображений, а `header_data` проходишь циклом и отправляешь прямиком на экран.

Упаковка в `unsigned char` это в восемь раз больше чем нужно, но зато никакой логики в программе на контроллере. В формате PBM (text) будет последовательность текстом `0101010...`

Если сохранить в PBM (raw, binary) , то читаешь по байту и дополнительным циклом со сдвигом получай единицы и нули.

```
for b in data:
    for i in xrange(8):
        yield (b >> i) & 1
```

Comment: Изображение-режим-индексированное и потом сохраняй в h или pbm text

Comment: все очень круто, но я тупой. У меня 10я винда и GIMP2.10.20. Пример изображения я закинул в начало вопроса. Оно уже черно-белое и всего 20х10рх. Дальше. Изображение->режим->индексировать. Там диалоговое окно. выбираю использовать 1-битную палитру. "преобразовать". Дальше файл->экспротировать как. "выберите тип файла" И нет "заголовочный файл h". А. наверное это "заголовок исходного кода С" расширение h

Comment: получилось. и при экспорте в h и в pbm. файл открывается с помощю Atom и там уже можно читать единицы нолики как душе угодно

Answer (score 5):

Попробуй так:

```
with open(path, mode="rb") as pbmfl:
    br = pbmfl.read()

def alignment(bin_num, target_len):
    cur_len = len(bin_num)
    if cur_len < target_len:
        return f'{"0"*(target_len-cur_len)}{bin_num}'
    else:
        return bin_num


bin_data = [alignment(f'{bs:b}', 8) for bs in list(br)])
print(''.join(bin_data))
```

Здесь функция `alignment` выравнивает полученные двоичные числа по указанной длинне

Comment: а можно поподробней вот это волшебство расписать? : return f'{"0"*(target_len-cur_len)}{bin_num}'. и вот это f'{bs:b}. И 8 потому что 8 бит или это другая восьмерка?

Comment: `f'{}'` - это интерполяция строки, то есть подстановка внутрь строки результата выполнения некоего кода, заключенного в скобках. Запись `bs:b` - это приведение числа `bs` к бинарному виду. То есть `23` в десятичной при вводе `f'{23:b}'` вернет `'10111'`. Ну и 8 - потому что да, 8 бит. Можно в принципе и 16 поставить, если нужно выравнивать по 16 бит

Comment: `f'{"0"*(target_len-cur_len)}{bin_num}'` - здесь, по сути, то же самое. Одновременно выполняется форматирование и конкатенация составляющих строки. Выражение состоит из двух частей - `{"0"*(target_len-cur_len)}` - добивание слева недостающего числа нулей до целевой длинны бинарного числа; и `{bin_num}`  - вывод самого бинарного числа.

Comment: [Вот здесь](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) в офф доках об инреполяции подробнее.